# IOS Swift handle global events

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, events

How can I handle global events triggered by the notification centre for example in my API class I fire an event if an error response is received e.g. (500). When that event is fired an UIAlert should be displayed on what ever view controller is active, or on logout the login view controller should be presented.

As far as I can see there is no easy way to get the current view controller in order to interact with it. (Note that my root view controller is *NOT* a navigation controller).

Comment: try `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: I do use NSNotification for broadcasting / observing the events. It just I am unsure how to handle things like presenting an alert on the active view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this way too hard to get current view controller ( when not using navigation controller ) ?

```
// on your app delegate    
getCurrentViewController(self.window!.rootViewController!)

func getCurrentViewController(viewController:UIViewController)-> UIViewController{

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
       return getCurrentViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }

    if let viewController = viewController?.presentedViewController {

        return getCurrentViewController(viewController)

    }else{

        return viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work but I am guessing it might screw up if one of the view controllers is a navigation controller. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: @Ben_hawk check the edited answer. I think this will solve issues when using navigation controller only, when not using navigation at all and when combining navigations with view controllers in different scenarios

Comment: Thanks this looks good, would you agree that it is the correct way to handle something like this?, e.g.

Comment: In the simplest form YES. Otherwise if you are applying any kind of architecture in your app it may violate it a bit

Comment: I think I'd rather design the app to avoid this sort of thing. Also can become more complicated as you use different custom views.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, that will work regardless of whether your view controllers are embedded in a `UINavigationController` or not, would be to subclass `UIViewController`. This class will handle receiving the `NSNotification` that an error occurred and will also handle displaying the alert:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                             selector: "errorOccured",
                                             name: "ErrorNotification",
                                             object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "ErrorNotification", object: nil)
    }

    func errorOccured() {
        // Present an UIAlertViewController or the login screen.
    }
}
```

Now, any `UIViewController`s that should display an alert when the error notification is posted just have to be a subclass of `MyViewController`. Just make sure, if you override `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear`, that you call `super.viewWillAppear` or `super.viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: This is a much better answer that others. This way the ViewController is taking responsibility for the view, and not your model telling it what to do.

Answer (score -1):

**For BroadCast Notification**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("erro400", object: nil)
```

**For Receive**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ErroOccure", name: "erro400", object: nil)
}

func ErroOccure()
{
    //present alert from here
   // do whatever you want
}
```

You have to Remove Notification when you finish with it.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: The pretty much what I have Except the issue is, this needs to be handled in all view controllers. For example getting a 500 when on the home page should render an alert, but it should also do that on the settings page, profile page etc. So it needs to handled globally, finding the active view controller and render the alert on it.

Comment: You will need to do this on all view controllers that use network communication. We're looking for a way to make it general

Comment: I know,i have answered because of he said he don't know how to handle notification.