# Cocoa/ How do I get a reference to current window's contentViewController in app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

How do I get a reference to current window's contentViewController in app delegate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30618635/1422333

Comment: My question is about OSX development. Thank you. @zellb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be two possible definitions for what you mean by "Current" window
The key window is the window that receives the key events (keep in mind this could be a panel within a window), while the main window is the current parent window that is open, but doesn't necessarily receive the key events.

You can access either of these windows with these lines, and subsequently grab a reference to their `contentViews`:

```
   [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView];
   [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] contentView];
```